# CSS Selector for Child of Parent's Sibling Element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I've got this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" id="trigger">Trigger</a>
</div>
<div class="sibling">
    <div id="change">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Is there a selector to grab #change when #trigger is hovered upon?

Like upon hover of #trigger, change the background of .sibling's #change element.

I'm looking for a pure CSS solution without javascript.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**In a word: no.**

Given the current structure of your HTML (and the current state of CSS selectors), this is not possible. Perhaps we will get something like this in CSS4, but traversal like this is best left up to Javascript.

You can obviously restructure your markup, and use the sibling selector:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" id="trigger">Trigger</a>
    <div class="sibling">
       <div id="change">Hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#trigger:hover + .sibling #change {
  color:red; 
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKfma)

Comment: Cool thanks Nick for your answer and your example on how I can restructure my markup to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot achieve this using CSS only. Javascript is a good option in this case..

You can however detect the `.parent` being hovered (which will solve your problem if the parent surrounds exactly the trigger):

```css
.parent:hover + .sibling div#change{background:red;}
```

(markup stays the same [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8f6Vv/1/))