# CSS - child of a sibling

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this:

```html
<section class="menu-items">
<header class="menu-group-header">
  <h1 class="menu-group-title">TITLE</h1>
</header>
<article id="post-315" class="post-315 nova_menu_item type-nova_menu_item status-publish hentry nova_menu-asd123">
 <header class="entry-header">
  <h3 class="entry-title">asd</h3> 
  </header>
 <div class="entry-content">
 sth
 </div>
 <span class="menu-price">100</span>
</article>
</section>
```

I need to change font for the TITLE (**h1** block). As I posted only partial HTML code, it is important that I use **#post-315** as a reference in the CSS (I'm adding custom CSS in wordpress to override theme's original). Is there a reason for which code below is not working?

```css
#post-315 ~ header > h1 {background: #5C5C5C; 
font-size: 200%; 
font-family: arial;}
```

It seems I cannot deploy it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793446/css-selector-for-child-of-sibling-element).

Comment: `header` is a child of `#post-315`, not a sibling ...

Comment: You are trying to select the previous sibling. There is no such facility in CSS.

Comment: You can't select previous sibling in CSS

Comment: Exactly I was trying to select the previous sibling. So there is no way around it then without modifying HTML?

Comment: Try this: `.postid-315 header > h1 {background: #5C5C5C; 
font-size: 200%; 
font-family: arial;}`

Answer (score 1):

Because in CSS you can't go back in the DOM tree. Your `header` is placed before `#post-315`, so you can get it from there. The sibling selector `~` takes the **next** element matching your selection at the same level of your first selector, but it can't take a **previous** one.

#### **UPDATE:**

There is no way to select a previous sibling in CSS. You can use javascript for these case, or simply point to that element from a parent one (which isn't what you want as you said). Since you are using WordPress, you can use a hook to add a `style` tag just for the page who contains de post with ID 315:

```
function custom_style_for_315()
{
    if ( get_the_ID() == 315 )
    {
        ?>
            <style>
                .menu-group-title {
                    background: #5C5C5C; 
                    font-size: 200%; 
                    font-family: arial;
                }
            </style>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_style_for_315');
```

You can place these lines in the `functions.php` file of your current theme. These styles will be added to your document `<head>` if the current page you are navigating is the post with ID = 315. It's not the most elegant way, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an update. I don't really know anything about javascript or php, but I will do the backup of 'functions.php' , and definitely give it a try. I will reply later how it went.

Comment: Unfortunately the code isn't working. In the function there is `( get_the_ID() == 315 )`, whilst ID of sibling element is `post-315`. I changed that but it's not working either. Any ideas why?

Comment: @lieutenant07 It's not about the HTML element. Your HTML element with ID `post-315` should appear when you are in the page of the post with ID 315 of your database. With `get_the_ID()` you are checking the current page post ID and then comparing with the ID that you want. If it matches, these styles will be added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Siblings are elements which stands at one level, for example:

```
<body>
   <div class="section-1">
     <h1>Hello there</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="section-2"></div>
<body>
```

At this example siblins are `section-1` and `section-2`, but h1 is child element of the section-1. So section-1 is parent of the h1 element.

What you need is get h1 which is child element of header:

```
.menu-group-header > h1 {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this way I will modify all h1 blocks across the site, and I want to target only the one in the neighbourhood of #post-315

Comment: Ok, then Gerard said true, you cannot access previous element.